# Set the list separator in Mac

Tags: ms-office, settings, language

In Windows, **List separator** (`,` as shown in my system) is a parameter that we could set:

[image]

I'm trying to find this setting in my Mac, but I could not find it. Here is the only thing I could find:

[image]

It seems that this separator is used to separate arguments in Excel functions.

Does anyone know how to set the list separator in Mac?

PS: I'm using Mac OS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/447492/738512

Comment: @SolarMike It's not the same question.

Comment: Well, I use excel and "," and ":" work fine - as long as you know how to use the functions.

Comment: could you give some examples of lists where the list separator is use?

Comment: Where do you not get what you want in macOS?  i.e. Where are llist wrong is macOS.

Comment: I think the list separator is used in Excel formulas to separate arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that this separator is used to separate arguments in Excel functions.

Yes, it is used to delimit arguments in Excel functions and as the default field separator when saving Excel spreadsheets as CSV files.

However, it is only used if "Use system separators" is set in Excel's advanced options (which it is by default). And this setting can be overridden with Excel's own settings.

I'm not actually aware of any other (office) applications that actually use this system setting. (Although no doubt there are.) AFAIK, LibreOffice Calc uses only its own internal settings (Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc > Foruma > Separators > Function).

> Does anyone know how to set the list separator in Mac?

AFAIK there is no explicit setting for this in MacOS. It is instead deduced from the "Decimal" setting under "Number separators" (and "Currency"?) in the *regional settings*. ie. If a *comma* is used as the "Decimal" number separator (as in your screensheet) then a *comma* cannot be used as the "list separator" in Excel, so will instead default to a `;` (semicolon). If instead a dot (`.`) is used as the "Decimal" separator, then a *comma* can be used as the "list separator".

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1068437/43815) to [a related question on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/496614/function-argument-delimiter-excel-2011-for-mac-os-x) suggests that it is dependent on both the "Decimal" settings of "Number separators" *and* "Currency", although it's not clear to me why "Currency" would be significant here (at least not for the function argument delimiter).

Further reference:

- [Formula errors in Excel when list separator is not set correctly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formula-errors)
- [Superuser.com - Function argument delimiter - Excel 2011 for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/496614/function-argument-delimiter-excel-2011-for-mac-os-x)
- [StackOverflow.com - How to change the excel function separator “;” to “,”? on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897946/how-to-change-the-excel-function-separator-to)